# Change Google Drive password, NOT account login

Tags: google-drive, google-account

How do I change the Google Drive password so only I can access it? I am the creator of it, but do not want other users of the same account (six of us can access the same Google account), who have the account mail password to access the Google Drive without an invitation.

Comment: Impossible; Google Drive login is your Google Account; There is no way to separate them;  All Google Accounts have access to Google Drive.

Answer (score 7):

That's not possible.

Google uses one login for all features, so if you gave them the keys to the house, they can go in all the rooms.